# How to install package from 12.04 on 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, apt, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am on 14.04 (64-bits) and I want to install some `<package>:i386` packages from 12.04.

The reason I want to do this is because some of my 32-bit applications work well on 12.04 but not on 14.04.

How could I do that?

Comment: It is not recommended to mix different releases or distro repositories, you might wanna comment what actual problems are you having with what program(s).

Comment: I am running ModelSim DE 10.1g from Mentor Graphics. What I got is just a SIGSEGV(11) and a core dump file.

Comment: Have you contacted the developers of this payed software about your issues?

Comment: Ubuntu is not an official supported OS. :(    So there's no support from official.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to impair your system, than download the deb files an install with

```
sudo dpkg -i your_deb_file
```

but even that is not without risk. Preparing yourself that you could get problems.

Comment: That's lots of packages to download manually.

Comment: @EnzoChi Unfortunately, I can not change the fact that there are many files. As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid".